# Graphviz DOT arrange Nodes in circles, layout too "compact"

Tags: layout, graph, graphviz, dot

**I'm halfway there please see the edit**

OK here's my problem, I'm generating a graph of a python module, including all the files with their functions/methods/classes.

I want to arrange it so, that nodes gather in circles around their parent nodes, currently everything is on one gargantuan horizontal row, which makes the thing >50k pixels wide and also let's the svg converter fail(only renders about the half of the graph).

I went through the [docs](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) but couldn't find anything that seems to do the trick.

So the question is:
Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to layout the whole thing by myself? :/

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Andrews comment I've got the right layout, the only problem now is that it's a bit to "compact"... so the question now is, how to fix this?

[image: Test]

Comment: have you tried using the "neato" layout? It might give a result like what you want.

Comment: Just tried it via the command line switch -K, kinda works see my edit.

Comment: A little late, but when you get this overlapped layouts with neato just set "overlap=false".

Answer (score 36):

i've mentioned all of the most significant parameters that influence your current layout and then suggested values for those parameters. Still, i suspect you can get the layout that you want just from applying a couple of these suggestions.

- **reduce the edge weight**, eg, [weight=0.5]; this will make the
  edges longer, causing the tight
  clusters you currently see in your
  graph to 'fan out'.
- **get rid of the node borders**, node_A
  [color=none; shape=plaintext];
  especially for oval-shaped nodes, a
  substantial fraction of the total
  node space is 'unused' (ie, not used
  to display the node label).
- **explicitly set the font size for
  the nodes** (the node borders are
  enlarged so that they surround the
  node text, which means that the font
  size and amount of text for a given
  node has a significant effect on its
  size); [fontsize=11] should be large
  enough to be legible yet also reduce
  the 'cluttered' appearance (the
  default size is 14).
- **increase minimum separation between
  nodes, via 'nodesep'**; eg, nodesep=2.0; this will
  directly address your objection
  regarding your graph being "too
  compact."  ('nodesep' and 'ranksep'
  probably affect how dot draws a graph
  more than any other parameters for
  node, edge, or graph. In your case,
  it looks like you have only two ranks
  of nodes; 'ranksep' sets the minimum
  distance between nodes of *different*
  ranks--it looks like all of the nodes
  that comprise your graph are of the
  same rank (except for few top level
  nodes in the centers).
- **explicitly set total graph size**, eg,
  size="7.75,10.25" (ensures that your
  graph fits on an 8.5 x 11 page and
  that it occupies the entire space)
- And one purely aesthetic suggestion
  that at most will only help your
  graph *appear* less cluttered: the
  default fontcolor for both edges and
  nodes is black. The majority of the
  ink on your graph is from those two
  structures (particularly if you
  remove the node borders), so i would
  for instance set either the node
  (text) fontcolor or the edge
  fontcolor to "blue" to help the eye
  distinguish the two sets of graph
  structures.

Comment: In fact, i had a very similar issue reported here and using the `ranksep` was the key configuration to fan out the graph. Thanks!

Comment: Could you lead me to documentation of this? With working code samples?

Answer (score 7):

If it is too compact, you will want to mess with the edge length. You have a couple options depending on the graph layout:

1. If your layout is sfdp or fdp, tweak the **graph** property *K*. Default is 0.3.
2. For neato (or fdp), tweak the **edge** property *len*. Default is 1.0 for neato and 0.3 for fdp.
3. For dot you can use the **edge** property *minlen* which is the minimum edge length. Default is 1.

You might also want to mess with the graph property *model* which determines clustering behavior. Specifically, try *subset*. I believe this handles *len* for you:
http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:model

Also, you can remove overlaps all together with scaling techniques: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:overlap

Answer (score 0):

I have around 500 nodes and used doug's recommendation.

This is my sample code that works (in python):

```
f = Digraph('companies',filename='companies.gv',
          edge_attr={'weight':'1',
                     'fontsize':'11',
                     'fontcolor':'blue',
                     'len':'4'},
          graph_attr={'fixedsize':'false', 
                      'bgcolor':'transparent'},
          node_attr={'fontsize':'11', 
                     'shape':'plaintext', 
                     'color':'none',
                     'fontcolor':'black'})

f.attr(layout="neato")
f.attr(nodesep='3')
f.attr(ranksep='3')
f.attr(size='5000,5000')
```